# Internal Server Error In Web Application Project

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have a Dynamic application in which I have a JSP file which is sending a string to a Servlet which is in another project which is a Web application Project. I am using Tomcat server in JSP project and the server is starting just fine but when I am trying to run the web application on local host I am getting HTTP ERROR 500
Problem accessing /jsptoservlettocloud. Reason: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR

This is my JSP FILE

```
<body>
<% 
   String str= "Shanx";

   URL u = new 
       URL("http://localhost:8080/ServletToCloud/JSPToServletToCloudServlet");

       HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection)u.openConnection();
       huc.setRequestMethod("GET");
       huc.setDoOutput(true);

       ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(huc.getOutputStream());
       objOut.writeObject(str);
       objOut.flush();
       objOut.close();
%>  
 </body>
```

This is my Servlet Class

```
public class JSPToServletToCloudServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
String str;
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)   
    throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
         ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(request.getInputStream());

        try
            {
                str= (String) ois.readObject();
        }

         catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

         finally
         {
        ois.close();
         }
    System.out.println("Servlet received : " + str); 
}
 }
```

This is my Web.xml file

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JSPToServletToCloud</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>pack.exp.JSPToServletToCloudServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JSPToServletToCloud</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/jsptoservlettocloud</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

In the url ServletToCloud is the name of the web application project and JSPToServletToCloudServlet is the name of the servlet. Is this url correct.

Comment: what does your web.xml look like?

Comment: u r making a "huc.setRequestMethod("POST");" request and ur servlet is orriding doGet() not doPost()

Comment: @ rocketboy
I have added it in the question.

Comment: @ Arvind
I have checked it with that also still getting the same error

Comment: What are you getting in the logs ? Any exception or errors ?

Comment: @  Saif Asif
WARNING: /jsptoservlettocloud: java.io.EOFException

Comment: I am getting exception in this line ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(request.getInputStream());

Answer (score 0):

In your jsp you have `http://localhost:8080/ServletToCloud/JSPToServletToCloudServlet` but you have `/jsptoservlettocloud` in your web.xml 
Your mapping is wrong.